# Cant draw on character

Tags: shaders, uv-image-editor, texture-paint-mode

I know the question has been asked many times, but I could not find a solution to my problem. I have created a character, but in Texture Paint Mode i cant draw on the image:

[image]

I added a UV map and created an image texture (BODY) and added it to the material. Still I can't draw. I also do not get any error messages. Here are two more images:

[image]

[image]

I would be happy if someone can help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello, make sure that you have not enabled a texture for your brush, if so, close it. If it's not the case, please pack your image and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Many many thanks. I had activated a texture on my brush. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have not enabled a texture for your brush, if so, close it:

[image]